# Undefined $auth in Vue using @websanova/vue-auth

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, jwt, vue-auth

I am trying to create SPA using Vue.js and Laravel as backend. I am using `tymon/jwt-auth` for JWT Authentication at the backend.

I cannot find $auth in my Login.vue.

I included @websanova/vue-auth in my app.js like this

```
...
import {createAuth}          from '@websanova/vue-auth/dist/v3/vue-auth';
import driverAuthBearer      from '@websanova/vue-auth/dist/drivers/auth/bearer.esm.js';
import driverHttpAxios       from '@websanova/vue-auth/dist/drivers/http/axios.1.x.esm.js';
import driverRouterVueRouter from '@websanova/vue-auth/dist/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x.esm.js';
...
var auth = createAuth({
    plugins: {
        http: axios,
        router: router
    },
    drivers: {
        http: driverHttpAxios,
        auth: driverAuthBearer,
        router: driverRouterVueRouter,
    },
    options: {
        rolesKey: 'type',
        notFoundRedirect: {name: 'user-account'},
    }
});

Vue.use(auth);
```

But this gives me `Uncaught TypeError: vue.reactive is not a function`

I followed latest implementation as instructed at [@websanova/vue-auth site](https://websanova.com/docs/vue-auth/guides/startup)

I also tried some old tutorials [this](https://codeburst.io/api-authentication-in-laravel-vue-spa-using-jwt-auth-d8251b3632e0) and [this](https://codebriefly.com/laravel-jwt-authentication-vue-js-spa-part-2/) using v2 of the package, but in that case this.$auth is undefined in Login.vue

Here's my complete [app.js](https://gist.github.com/pankajjha/ae0da57176923affcc0a467e1ae42652) and [Login.vue](https://gist.github.com/pankajjha/8117897d770d46b65b85aaf3621a773e)